# format float number in Java (#.###.##)

Tags: java, android, formatting, decimalformat

I'd like to format float numbers in a pretty manner like so:

1432.432342003  to 1.432,43

I can format it from 1432.432342003  to 1432,43 loike so:

```
 DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
 String pretyStr = decimalFormat.format(input);
```

so how to achieve this, maybe there is a easy way like #.###.## - I don't want to take int part aside and float part aside

Comment: Did you check [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36418901/change-decimalformat-locale)?

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323502/how-to-set-thousands-separator-in-java) also

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change DecimalFormat locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36418901/change-decimalformat-locale)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##");
 String pretyStr = decimalFormat.format(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called a thousands separator, in english-speaking countries the usual format is 12,345,678.90

You may use the following format with DecimalFormat: `###,###.###`
The result of 123456.789 with this format shoudl be 123,456.789

You can find more information on DecimalFormat [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)

EDIT1:
 Example

```
 DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###.##");
```

Answer (score 0):

The format you're looking for is

`DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##");`

But be careful, separators may change with your locale, and you may need to use a NumberFormat to control that

Answer (score 0):

I got it like so:

```
  public static String getPrettyPrintVal(double input){
    final DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###.###", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY));
    return decimalFormat.format(input);
}
```

3214234.234 ==> 3.214.234,234