# DecimalFormat is parsing number wrong. Why?

Tags: java, decimalformat

I currently create a basic Java application that allows parsing a provided number into a formatted String.
The issue I face right now is, that the DecimalFormat formats the provided value in the wrong format.

Example:

```java
private final DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();

public static void main(String[] args){
    int number;
    try{
        number = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
        System.out.println("The provided value was invalid!");
        System.exit(0);
        return;
    }

    format.applyPattern("#,###,###.##");

    return format.format(number);
    System.exit(0);
}
```

The issue I face here is, that if I, for example, provide the number `123456789` as the first argument in the jar command, will it return `123'456'789` and not the desired result of `123,456,789`.

What could cause this issue?

Comment: Have you checked your locale? It could be that the default locale has set the grouping separator to the `'`. You could check the grouping separator by `format.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator()`.

Answer (score 0):

With the `java.text.DecimalFormat` import, and this code:

```
private static final DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 1456781;

        format.applyPattern("#,###,###.##");

        System.out.println("The formatted version is -> " + format.format(number));
    }
```

the output I get is

```
The formatted version is -> 1,456,781

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So it seems to format it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

What I can see as an issue here is that you are returning `Integer` instead of void in the return. Also, you are accessing non-static function `format` from a static function. You can move this inside your function, or use as a static variable.

```
private static DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();

public static void main(String[] args){
    int number;
    try{
        number = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
        System.out.println("The provided value was invalid!");
        System.exit(0);
        return;
    }

    format.applyPattern("#,###,###.##");

    System.out.println(format.format(number));
    System.exit(0);
}
```

If the above doesn't work, there's a good chance it's coming from your locale. You can force locale using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36418901/change-decimalformat-locale)