# Java 11 - Display decimal in Czech Korona # ###,## Kč format

Tags: java

**Java 11**

I'm dealing with Czech karona currency and need to display

```
50427.1 as 50 427,10 Kč
```

Tried,

```
System.out.println(new java.text.DecimalFormat("## ###,00 Kč").format(Double.valueOf("50427.1")));
```

But its printing as

```
5,04,27  Kč
```

How can i make it to display in the correct format?

Comment: Did you specify your locale? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36418901/change-decimalformat-locale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify the format; just use the locale's currency formatter:

```
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("cs-CZ")).format(50427.1)
```

If you want to include the trailing 0 decimals, you can `setMinimumFractionDigits(2)`.

[**Ideone Demo**](https://ideone.com/A3dm45)

Comment: Tried for 50427.1 and 209, got output as 50 427,10 Kč and 209,00 Kč. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Specify the locale to use in order to propely format the values

```
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("#,###.00 ¤", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("cs-CZ"))).format(50427.1));
```

will output

```
50 427,10 Kč
```

Comment: Thanks @jonnathan Q, it worked.